# How do you order a nominale variable. e.g month in R?

Tags: r

This is a very basic problem but I do not find an answer. How can I order my variable "Month" so that when I make a bar plot January is first, then February...?

Thank you so much,

Comment: can you give a reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@PhilipPham's answer is correct: this is equivalent but a little simpler:

```
Month <- factor(Month,levels=month.name)
```

since there is a built-in `month.name` variable in R that gives the English month names in order.

Answer (score 2):

```
df$Month <- factor(df$Month,format(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"),by="1 month",length=12),"%B"))
```

Then, plot again.

Comment: Thank you! In fact my column already contains only the month : "January", "February"... but I a wondering what to write in the barplot script to get January before February... because right now it is in alphabetical order...

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer from Ben (since I cannot add comments yet), you can do the following, assuming you have a dataframe with a Month column:

```
df$Month <- factor(df$Month,levels=month.name)
df = df[order(df$Month,decreasing=FALSE),]
```